# What is an efficient remote work setup you use while traveling?

Tags: work-environment, telecommute, travel

I'm about to begin working fully remote -- 100% away from a corporate office -- and am curious to what hardware setups have worked for people before.
I have a laptop and monitor with a docking station for my home office, but I'm interested in how to take a similar setup with me on the road.

I generally prefer(need) another screen since I routinely deal with geospatial data alongside database tables.

My team pretty much has the software side of the remote work down well, so I'm mostly concerned with the hardware setup side of things and how to make my work station super mobile without sacrificing too much connection speed or screen space.

What is an efficient remote work setup you use while traveling?

Comment: there are a few [portable second monitors](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?q=portable%20second%20monitor%20for%20laptop) that are USB powered specifically for this situation. I've never used one (for my work 17" @ 1920x1080 would be inadequate)

Comment: This will be different for every person. Some people can carry large laptops, some people can't, some people can carry large laptops but prefer smaller devices, some people rent co-working spaces on the road. There are simply too many options to have a "best" answer.

Comment: `I generally prefer(need) another screen`. I don't see how this is practical "on the road". How about use home office for the heavy geospatial data and when you're on the road handle some other tasks

Comment: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped... avoid asking subjective questions where …

    every answer is equally valid..." ([help/dont-ask])

Comment: How do you actually plan on working?  For me "working fully remote" means "100% of the time at home", where you can easily have a fixed workstation of comparable specs to whatever you'd use in the corporate office.  But it sounds like you mean you'll be traveling away from home/your home office the vast majority of the time?

Comment: @gnat where can I ask this type of question in its appropriate space?

Comment: not at Stack Exchange. ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mostly i am at office place, but employer provided me with [this monster](http://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/monitors/asus-mb168b.aspx) when ever i am out of office. I am very pleased. For internet i use mobile connection when ever there is 3G or 4G available. I have very good mobile internet over here at Latvia. So That is mostly my setup when i travel or have to work outside my casual work environment.

Also generally speaking i suggest find quite place, i have a table and good chair. I have few friends that work from home, and mostly there biggest challenge is when there is something happening in the place where they are trying to work. Use other room with locks or something like that.